# Math competition for school

Tags: contest-math

I am trying to find a math competition where a 10 year old kid can participate.

Can someone suggest a competition in USA?

Comment: Check out http://www.maa.org/math-competitions/. The AMC is available to all ages. I believe you can sit for the AMC 8.

Comment: [Mathcounts](https://www.mathcounts.org/) is another competition for middle schoolers in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

A great online competition we use is Beestar math competition. It also is super convenient and grade level specific. Also, a lot of students in Texas use it to prepare for Mathcounts (mentioned above). We also really like using Beestar math competition since it gives you a percentile ranking which gives you a really good guidance on how to help your kiddos in the next round.